# Adding /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 to path - installing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I am trying to install ruby via rvm.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p286
```

but I get the following error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p286.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

Refering to the last line of the error, how do I get 'usr/bin/gcc-4.2' in my path?

I have tried adding the following `PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` to my .bash_profile, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any GCC compiler installed on your system, and if so, is it GCC 4.2.x?  If you don't have any GCC at all, you'll need to get one (though GCC 4.2 is hardly current; that's 4.7.2, with 4.8 due out in a month or two).  If you have a GCC, what version is it.  If it is a 4.2.x version, you can go to `/usr/bin` and do `ln -s gcc gcc-4.2` with a clear conscience.  If you have a later version, you may decide to fib, and do the link anyway.  But your problem is that `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` does not point to a version of GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following:

```
rvm requirements
```

Then follow the steps as what is instructed.

Comment: Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
/Users/marty/.rvm/scripts/functions/build: line 68: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
Doing /usr/local/etc/openssl
cert.pem => 77ee3751.0

Comment: This helped me fix the problem in the original post. `rvm requirements` prints out a lot of useful information about your environment, with suggestions about how to configure each piece. I've written up the details on CoderWall: https://coderwall.com/p/p1g2kg